# Do OR with all array's members

Tags: ruby, bitmask

Suppose I have an array `[1,2,3,4]`, and I want to do `1 | 2 | 3 | 4` in `Ruby` language

How to write it faster?

Actually, I just read an article about `bitmask` at [CoderWall](https://coderwall.com/p/hpkbra) and I wonder when the `settings` have many options, such as `10` or `15`, I think write `(1 << 1 | 1 << 2 | 1 << 3` ... `| 1 << 15).to_s(2)` is too long.

Is there any way to write it shorter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
[1,2,3,4].inject(:|)
```

To create a bitmask I would do:

```
[1,2,3,4].map(&1.method(:<<)).inject(0, :|)
```

If you don't want to iterate twice, just add `.lazy` after array:

```
[1,2,3,4].lazy.map(&1.method(:<<)).inject(:|)
```

Comment: Personally I prefer the `reduce` alias.

Comment: So, with the question about `bitmask`, I write `(1..15).inject(0){|r, i| r | 1 << i}` is correct?